# first click slide right second click slide left with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

hello im trying to make something like github treeslider

im new to javascript..

but heres what im working on

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('#red-side-menu a').pjax({
        container: '#ajax-users-v1',
    });


    var toggle;
    if (typeof toggle != 'undefined') {
        toggle = true;
    }

    if (toggle) {
        $('body')
        .bind('start.pjax', function() { $('#ajax-users-v1').show("slide", { direction: "right" });  })
        .bind('end.pjax',   function() {  })
        toggle = false;
    };

    if (!toggle) {
    $('body')
      .bind('start.pjax', function() { $('#ajax-users-v1').show("slide", { direction: "left" });  })
      .bind('end.pjax',   function() {  })
      toggle = true;
    }


    $('#red-edit-full a').pjax({
        container: '#ajax-users-v1',
    });     
});
```

well before above im useing php to get $_GET['infolder'] but it seems its not that good.
**the problem now that it keeps slide to left**

is there a way to do this?

Comment: ok, what is your intended functionality as it isn't clear what you want to happen?

Comment: what can i do to make it,when first click it go to right the next click it will go to left.

Comment: Can you just describe what the desired behaviour re. the clicking is? When you first load the page, there is a link(s). When you click it, what happens? Then, if you click the link again, what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be simplified.

```
# this variable maintains state for the lifetime of the page
var direction = "right";
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  # this whole statement only executes once
  $('#red-side-menu a').pjax({
    container: '#ajax-users-v1'
  });

  # this line executes once
  $('body')
    # this line executes once
    .bind('start.pjax', function() {
      # this line executes every time the start.pjax event reaches the body element
      $('#ajax-users-v1').show("slide", { direction: direction });  
    })
    # this line executes once
    .bind('end.pjax', function() {
      # this line executes every time the end.pjax event reaches the body element (hint: this event is raised after start.pjax is finished) 
      direction = (direction == "right" ? "left" : "right"); 
    });

  # this whole statement only executes once
  $('#red-edit-full a').pjax({
    container: '#ajax-users-v1'
  });     
});
```

The document ready event automatically runs only once. I have commented the code to show when each line or statement block is executed. It's really important to understand that the code inside the event handlers is the only code that is going to run after the page is finished loading.

Answer (score 0):

Simply give a value to x outside the function

```
var x = true;
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ ...
```

Comment: that work!, but it seems i dont get how javascript work, lol. it give an animation to the right, then to left. what can i do to make it, after it go to right the next click it will go to left.

Comment: i think you should test the value of x inside the bind call back function

Comment: instead of two separate if statements try if/else. the way that is written when x is true both if statements will execute and both handlers will be bound to the same action.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here is that you declare `var x` without giving it a value. It is thus `undefined`, so `typeof x != 'undefined'` is false, so you don't end up setting `x` to true.

(What does `x` denote, by the way? Please name your variables something a human can understand...)

Then, since `undefined` is "falsy", the code inside `if (!x)` gets executed. `$('body')` gets bound those events, and `x` gets set to true.

Then the function you passed to `jQuery(document).ready` ends, and `x` goes out of scope, never to be seen again or used by anyone. So its existence was pretty pointless; you could have commented out all code except for that before `var x`, inside `if (!x)`, and `$('#red-edit-full a').pjax...`